# Issue running cron on MySQL Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, cron

I am working on setting up a cron to import database dumps into a MySQL container. However, I am trying a test cron to make sure everything is working correctly but I get no output.

My `Dockerfile` is setup as such

```
FROM mysql:8

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron

COPY /crons/test-cron /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
```

The MySQL image is successfully created and my test-cron can be found in `/etc/cron.d/test-cron` however I never get an output to the `cron.log` file I created.

`test-cron`

```
* * * * * root echo 'Written by cron' >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# empty line
```

My docker-compose.xml is setup as the following

```
version: '3'

services:
    data:
        build: ./data/
    db:
        build: ./db/
        volumes_from:
            - data
        volumes:
            - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=myDB
          - MYSQL_USER=myUser
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=Password
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password
          - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file crontab and add an entry like this

```
FROM mysql:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/test-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/test-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/test-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! turns out i did `COPY` instead of `ADD`